# I added Notes and Attachments in Related Lists of Opportunity still I am not able to see them in lightning but I can see them in classic?

Tags: lightning, administration, page-layout, attachment, notes

I added Notes and Attachments in Related Lists of Opportunity from page-layout still I am not able to see them in lightning but I can see them in classic? Why?

Answer (score 2):

Classic notes and attachments are not available in Lightning. You instead need to use [Files](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.collab_files_overview.htm&type=5) and [Enhanced Notes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.notes_admin_overview.htm&type=5). You can read more about [migrating](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000382732&type=1) data from the classic feature to the new features.